# Select random ids based on other unique id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For sample table:

```
ID courseId dishID
1  1        1
2  1        5
3  2        4
4  1        7
5  2        8
```

I wan`t to select by unique courseId random dishId. So my result would be

```
ID courseId dishId
1  1        1
3  2        4
```

And if I run again than other random :

```
ID courseId dishId
2  1        5
5  2        8
```

etc...

I am using microsoft sql 2008

For example

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE dishId IN
(SELECT MIN(dishId) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY courseId
```

That returns me right result but the dishId is always the same, but I want that dishId is random dish

Or I can select first from one table by courseId = 1 and than select again by courseId 2 (both results order by newId()) and make UNION, but when I have 7 courses, I don`t want to have 7 SELeCT sentances ... I hope I can get same result without UNION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ID, courseId, dishID from (
select row_number() over (partition by courseId order by newid()) as n, *
from Table 
) t
where n = 1
```